# library for SNA network and graph in R with extra dimensionality

Tags: r, graph-theory, networking, igraph

I have a csv of the following format:

person, location, time_of_day, money_spent

I've been going through and seeing how to format data to make it work with the more popular libraries (see: https://sites.google.com/site/daishizuka/toolkits/sna/sna_data), but they seem to be focused on various formats of expressing the connectedness between each member.

I would like to express extra dimensionality to my network by, say, coloring the nodes and connectors different colors according to time_of_day met, or change size of the various dots by money_spent.  Can someone give me some guidance as to how I can do that with an implementation of network graphs in R?

I can figure out how to preprocess my data such that it is compatible; I'm just not getting how to implement things to the liking of the SNA libraries such as igraph.

Comment: How is your network defined? Is this a bipartite network?

Answer (score 0):

The [networkDynamic](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkDynamic/index.html) R package provides data structures for dynamic networks and some basic functionality for importing and manipulating this type of data. You should then be able to do analysis with network, sna, or igraph packages (disclaimer:  I'm one of the maintainers of networkDynamic)